# Осуществление выполнения javascript-функции после конца построения DOM

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dom

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы после отправки комментария их модуль перезагружался заново.
С помощью AJAX ниже в нужный мне div вставляется содержимое страницы *page2.php*.

```
function func() {
  var text = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "/page2.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var request = "id=1";
  xmlhttp.send(request);
}
```

При вызове функции `func()` путём нажатия кнопки она выполняется прекрасно.
Но при отправке сообщения вызывается аналогичная функция, которая в случае успешной отправки вставляет в div код следующего содержания:

```
<script>func();</script>
```

При этом, код появляется на странице, но не выполняется. Уже пробовал добавлять во всевозможные обёртки listener'ов событий, но функция так и не выполняется. Подскажите, какой в этом случае делать код?

Comment: добавьте функцию отправки комментария

Comment: Это и есть func(). Она просто обращается к php-скрипту

Comment: тогда где вставляется `<script>func();</script>`? и зачем вообще вставлять тег скрипт, а не просто вызвать `func()` еще раз?